# How to check phonegap properly installed or not?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to install phonegap but its showing "npm warn engine xbuilder wanted node{'''} current node {'''}"..its a warning so is it successfully installed?how do i check whether successfully installed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed  `node.js`? If not install first and do the following steps

```
1. $ npm install -g phonegap@latest // to install phonegap
2. $ phonegap     //to ensure phonegap is installed
```

on performing step 2 you should get following in you command prompt

```
Usage: phonegap [options] [commands]
 Description:
  PhoneGap command-line tool.
  Commands:
     help [command]       output usage information
     create <path>        create a phonegap project
      ...
```

See the more detailed documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/) read the requirements carefully.

Comment: then please perform next 2 steps and tell me whether you get output after entering second command

Comment: i found- phonegap is not recognized as an external or internal command,operable program or batch file

Comment: C:\> npm install -g phonegap@latest
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})

Comment: npm install -g npm or npm update -g to update your npm. It seems your npm is at older version

Comment: Thanks i did that after running this command  npm install -g phonegap@latest i got error at last line "npm ERR! code 1
 "

Comment: Sorry but don't have any clues regarding this...thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

Just write "phonegap" in your console. If you have output, it is installed. Else you get "command not found"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem so I just ignore the message because there is a problem with the new version of node which is **node 0.12.x**. `

Uninstall the latest version and try to install the previous version of node like **node 0.10.x**.

Download Node link: [Node v0.10.36 (Stable)](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.36/)

Hope it might work for you.